# Social, Accounts framework to get user info from facebook (profile image,name,etc)

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios6

This is my facebook method:

```
- (void)getMeFacebook{

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    __block ACAccount *facebookAccount = nil;

    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    // Specify App ID and permissions

    NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey : @"1405219416361729",

                              ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email", @"publish_stream"],

                              ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends};

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType

                                          options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)

     {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

             facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

             NSLog(@"Granted!!!");

         }

         else {

             NSLog(@"error.localizedDescription======= %@", error.localizedDescription);

         }

     }];


    NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

    facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];


    NSLog(@"Break 1");
```

When debugging the code, it never evaluates if(granted), seems like the method requestAccessToAccountsWithType is not behaving correctly.I have already check for the facebook settings in the app but still not working.

Any idea of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of debugging and research i reach the solution, everytime you have to debug a block (callback) of a method in objective-c, its needed to add extra breaktimes inside the block.

The issue was a problem of synchronism, as the method was call in the main.m and the **UIAlert** requesting permission to access facebook data in the iPhone never appears. I move the call of the method to the viewDidLoad and the entire app work ok!